# Is validating a userId (or any other data extracted from an authentication token) necessary?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

In my controller action as have something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("approve")]
[Authorize(Policy = "Approve")]
public IActionResult GetEntitiesToBeApproved()
{
    var stringUserId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")?.Value;
    Guid.TryParse(stringUserId, out var userId);
    if (userId == default(Guid))
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ConstantValues.InvalidUserId);
    }
    //service calls etc.
    return Ok();
}
```

Is there any point in checking that the userId is valid (non-default) or can I skip it?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip it, Authorize filter attribute check it for You.